# Is the following relation a well-order?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, well-orders

Suppose, $A$ is a well-ordered set with strict well-order $<_A$. Suppose $B$ is the set of all bijections from $A$ to $A$. Let’s define a relation $<_B$ on $B$ in the following way: $b <_B a$ iff $\exists c \in A$, such that $b(c) <_A a(c)$ and $\forall d <_A c$ $b(d) = a(d)$. Is $<_B$ always a strict well-order?

I know that it is always a strict total order, because it is both transitive and trichotomous. If $A$ is finite, then it is also a well-order. But what is about the general case?

Comment: Isn't this simply the _lexicographic order_ on the permutations of A?

Comment: @IvanNeretin, yes it is.

Comment: If $A$ is countable, then $B$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, so if this worked it would give you an explicit well-ordering of $\mathbb{R}$, which is more or less known not to exist (depending on exactly how you define "explicit").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, this is simply the lexicographic order on the permutations of A.

Say, A is the set corresponding to the ordinal $\omega+1$, that is, $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,\omega\}$. Now consider the following infinite series of permutations:
$$\begin{aligned}
a_1=&[\omega,2,3,4,\dots,1]\\
a_2=&[1,\omega,3,4,\dots,2]\\
a_3=&[1,2,\omega,4,\dots,3]\\
\vdots\\
\text{etc.}
\end{aligned}
$$
etc.

Clearly each $a_i$ is smaller than the previous, but where is the smallest element?

Answer (score 5):

Ivan Neretin gives a nice answer. I will show that your order is not well-ordered even if the ordertype of $A$ is $\omega$.

Consider the following sequences:
$$a_n= \langle \underbrace{0,1,2,3,\cdots,2n-2,2n-1}_{\text{$2n$ terms}}, 2n+1, 2n, 2n+3,2n+2,\cdots\rangle$$

(The previous example is not bijective, so I changed the example.)

For example, $a_0=\langle1,0,3,2,5,4,\cdots\rangle$ and $a_1=\langle0,1,3,2,5,4,\cdots\rangle$. We can see that $a_0>a_1>a_2>\cdots$ under the lexicographic order.

Comment: I was just about to post a very similar example, such that the definition of $a_n$ may be simpler to state:  Let $a_n$ be the permutation that swaps $n$ and $n+1$ and leaves everything else fixed. Then $a_1>a_2\dots$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: That's a very nice counterexample because it shows that already for permutations changing only finitely many elements, you don't get a well-order.